# what is time complexity of given code for searching?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

what is time complexity of this code?

I have tried solving this using binary search but it cannot be solved in that way please help to find the complexity of this code.

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>a[i];
        int x;
    cin>>x;
    int p=-1;
    int q=n;
    while(p+1<q)
    {
        int m=(p+q)/2;
        if(a[m]<x)
        p=m;
        else
        q=m;
    }
    cout<<"j";
}
```

Comment: "`#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;`" <-- two bad habits you should get rid of.

Comment: To expand on @JesperJuhl’s comment: [Avoid `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721). [Avoid `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095).

Comment: BTW, online judges and code competitions do not teach good coding habits.  Industry software engineers will reject this code in a code inspection and make you rewrite it.  Rarely, do shops require this kind of code (if they do, they have horrible project managers and poor project scheduling techniques).

Comment: Re-Tagged the question

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

p=m+1;
else 
q=m-1;

Also terminate when you have found the element. The complexity is that of binary search, log(n).